# Bootstrap Spacing what is md?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, spacing

[image]

In the div tag above picture, what does md means ?

1. mx-auto: margin on the x-axis set to auto in other words, center the element horizontally.
2. ml-md-0: Set margin left to 0 ?
3. mr-md-auto: Set margin right to auto ?

If 1,2,3 are correct, then aren't above classes not only redundant but also contradict one another ?

From the 1. element margin is set to auto, but then in 2. element margin set to 0 again.

Can someone explain what those three bootstrap classes are doing please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is [mobile-first](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/#core-concepts), meaning whatever you define at smaller [breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) will cascade up to larger breakpoints until overridden, so:

- **`mx-auto`:** Center horizontally for mobile devices and up (aka all devices)
- **`ml-md-0`:** Apply `ml-0` only for `md` devices and up (mobile and `sm` devices will still have `mx-auto`)
- **`mr-md-auto`:** Apply `mr-auto` only for `md` devices and up (mobile and `sm` devices will still have `mx-auto`)

Note that the listed order of `class` strings doesn't matter, so for example `mr-md-auto ml-md-0 mx-auto` would have the same effect. Bootstrap will apply its styles in [mobile-first](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/#core-concepts) order.

Answer (score 0):

The term "md" refers to medium as per the responsiveness (breakpoint) of that element.

You also have small (sm), large (lg), and extra large (xl).

You can check more detailed info about the grid obtions of bootstrap here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options